# Select Linked operation ("L" key) doesn't work on my model

Tags: edit-mode, import, topology, shortcut

I imported this model from Roblox studio, and I tried to select all the faces on the outside but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

[image: spider model, selected linked vertices]

Watch [this video](https://youtu.be/apS7fIu3Pn8) to understand the structure of the imported model, as at the end I show how it looks from the inside.

[image: model from the inside]

Update:

Merging the vertices by distance (<kbd>M</kbd>) worked in a way, but now the face (egg) and the hatched shell do not overlap: https://youtu.be/C-Vhd00e_Ec

Comment: merge by distance?

Comment: It worked in a way, but now the face (egg) and the hatched shell do not overlap
https://youtu.be/C-Vhd00e_Ec

Comment: The `L` shortcut works perfectly fine in the first video. It selects all vertices linked to the one you hover your mouse over (or close to) when pressing the key. The reason it selects only a few is that the mesh is a bunch of unconnected pieces. Just because two faces are next to each other they are not necessarily connected - most likely they have their own separate vertices lying in the same location. Using _Merge by Distance_ now merges everything within a threshold. Is it too small it might not merge all it should, is t too big then perhaps some unwanted parts are merged as well.